# Prolog - Display prime numbers

Tags: prolog, primes

I am new to Prolog programming so still learning. I'm tryingto create a program that accepts a value X and returns a list of all prime numbers between 6 and X. I'll also be later adding an error output if X is entered as 6 or lower.

I have come up with the below code so far to have the value of x entered, y as the first prime number and the counter as 1. Even this is not working, as I try to increment the values of Y. If i can get this working I plan to then add conditions to only show Y if it is a prime, by checking that it divides by itself and 1.

If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

```
prime (X, Y, Counter) :-
    X >= Y,
    writeln(Y),
    Next is Y + Counter,
    prime (X, Next, Counter).

prime(X, Y, _) :-
     Y > X.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spaces in `prime (` here and here:

[image: Screenshot of source code]

Then it works to call `?- prime(10, 3, 1).` and have it count.

Comment: Thanks @TessellatingHeckler. I'm just getting a chance to revisit this now, since last week but you but answer helped me. I didn't realise my mistake in the spacing on my code. Do you know the best method to go to get my program to then list all prime numbers between 6 and my chosen value Y?